# Register sharpshell assembly with setup.

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation, sharpshell

I was looking for a way to add a menu item on right click for special files until I found this article [SharpShell](http://sharpshell.codeplex.com/)

I was able to write my modified shell and to register it using ServerManager.exe.

How can i register my shell in a system when the user installs my program with a setup?

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways. The first is to use regasm to register the server, but that tool must be on the end-users machine. The other is to use a custom action and install the server programatically:

```
ServerRegistrationManager.InstallServer(typeof(MyServer), RegistrationType.OS64Bit, true);
ServerRegistrationManager.RegisterServer(typeof(MyServer), RegistrationType.OS64Bit);
```

The Server Registration Manager comes with SharpShell and writes all of the appropriate keys to the registry for you.